# Extra blank page added to the end of SSRS report when it is exported as Word document from Dynamics 365 on-premise report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2016

I have created a custom SSRS report which is ran from an Invoice record in Dynamics 365 on-prem.

If the report consists of more than one page and I choose to export the report as a Word document, an extra blank page is added to the end of the report. If the report only consists of one page, the extra page is not added.

When the report is exported as a PDF, or a printer-friendly PDF version of the report is generated via the print button, the extra page is not there.

The blank page, when looked at in Word, only shows the page number in the footer and a carriage return at the very top of the page.

There were issues with extra white-space in this report previously, which was resolved by setting `ConsumeContainerWhitespace` to `True`.

I have looked at every textbox, rectangle, tablix on the report looking for a possible cause of this blank page, but have not been able to find one. There are no `PageBreaks` added before, between, or after any elements on the report.

If the items continue from the first page, to the second page, the report should only be two pages long. If the report has items on 3 pages, there should only be 3 pages in the report, etc.

After spending a lot longer than anticipated on this issue, I came here to ask for some assistance. The report should not have any blank sheets in it.

Comment: I have faced similar issue for lot of my reports. Main culprit in such issues are mostly your Report size and your body size. You will have to make sure your Body size is withing your Report size including if you have any margin Top, Bottom, Left and Right. I believe mostly Report width is of 21 cm and if you have 1 cm margin on all side so your body of report should be 20 cm. Try this and let me know

Comment: Report size is 8.5 x 11 in. Margins are: left: 0.5 in, right: 0.5  in, top: 0.4 in, bottom 0.4 in. Body size is  7.23267 in x 6.1 in. I have checked all margins and am still getting this extra sheet. The weird thing is it only happens when the report goes onto two or more pages.